# Session Variables Between Pages

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got two pages with many text box inputs containing numbers.
The first page's form submits to the second page (where the text box values become session vars) and the second page submits all of the session vars to a processing page where they're added to the database.

I'm trying to make it where you can go back and forth between page 1 and 2, and all of your text values entered will stay the same.

This works for coming back to the first page because the second page initiates the variables and takes the POST.

However, I can't achieve the same effect going from the second page back to the first, and then back, because the second page only submits to the processing page. Example:

```
<div style="width:800px;text-align:LEFT;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:5px;">
  <input type="submit" value="<-- Back to Parts A-C" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;color:blue;text-decoration:underline">
</div>
<div style="width:800px;text-align:right;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:5px;">
  <input type="submit" value="Save Report" /></form></p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find a way for Page 1 to be able to receive the text box inputs from page 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could set a session variable on a change event and have the page populate the input fields when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by putting the values that the user enters in session immediately when they submit any form, even if it's not the final form before saving to the database.

I've never used php, but you should be able to write some code like this:

```
<input type='text' name='txtName', value={if name in session, print name here, otherwise ""} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I should have included some more code, I've got:`<td><input type="text" name="DispCTONonCapCases" size="5" id="DispCTONonCapCases" value="<?php setText('DispCTONonCapCases');?>/></td>` but my main problem is that I can go back to the first page and submit the form at the same time. As page2's form declaration is: `<form method="POST" action="processreport.php">` the submit link that I'd like to take me back to the first page will only goto processreport.php